# grep upto matching brackets

Tags: shell-script, sed, awk

I have a file like this:-

```
pin(ABC) {  
              a b c d e f {  
              abc  
              }  
             }  
pin(XYZ) {  
              g h i j k  {  
                      j k {  
                        cg {  
                     }  
                    }  
                   }  
                  }  
abcd pqrs rstu  
mango banana tree  
pin(PQR) {  
               mango  
         }
```

Now i want to grep the text like this:-
when i give ABC as input then output should be a file named ABC with the content from "pin(ABC) {" upto matching bracket "}" like this :-

```
pin(ABC) {  
              a b c d e f {  
              abc  
              }  
             }
```

when i give PQR the output should be a file named PQR with this content:-

```
pin(PQR) {  
               mango  
         }
```

& so on for any word which is inside pin()
one way to do it is to grep the text from "pin(ABC" till next name "pin" & direct the output to the file named "ABC" , it works for only ABC but fails for case of PQR & XYZ.
How to do it.

Comment: Grep has a `-A` option, which can specify how many lines to show after the match - this does have the problem that you need to know how many lines that need to be shown.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
$ pcregrep -Mo 'pin\(ABC\) (\{([^{}]++|(?1))*\})' file
pin(ABC) {
              a b c d e f {
              abc
              }
             }
```

If you don't have `pcregrep` but have GNU `grep` and it has been built with support for PCRE patterns and your file is not too big and doesn't contain NUL characters, you can do:

```
grep -zPo 'pin\(ABC\) (\{([^{}]++|(?1))*\})' file
```

Those (`pcregrep` and `grep -P`) are using PCRE patterns that support recursive regex operators.

`pcregrep -M` turns on the multiline mode (where `pcregrep` can pull several lines as needed while matching the regexp) and `grep -z` tells the records are NUL-separated instead of being *lines*.

The trick above is in the `(?1)` operator that means *the regexps inside the **first** paren group* so we have a recursive regexp: we're matching `{` followed by a sequence of 0 or more (`*`) sequences of non-brace characters (`[^{}]++`, `++` being the possessive version of `+`) *or* the regexp in the outer `(...)` again (`{` followed by...).

See the man page for `pcrepattern` for details. That's copied almost verbatim from an example in there.

Using `perl`:

```
perl -l -0777 -ne 'print $& while /pin\(ABC\) (\{([^{}]++|(?1))*\})/g'
```

(like for `grep` it slurps the whole file in memory).

Comment: Thanks for reply, It would be better if you can explain it your answer in step by step so that i can learn your approach.

Comment: Hi Stephane , it is not working for some words in my original file, i don't know why , Can we have any other solution.If you want the original file then i can post it but it have 21142 line & its size is 7.6M .Please reply.

Comment: @yogendrasingh, yes paste it somewhere like on pastebin. Hard to tell what's wrong without seeing the file.

Comment: Stephane , i have done it somehow, i just deleted all the previous lines before the search pattern , so my file became shorter. Then it works for all patterns  one by one,May be the reason being because of big file.Anyways Thanks for giving your time :)