# Why Blank output of this `sed ... <<END_SED | cut ...`?

Tags: text-processing, sed

The following sed returns (`...| od -c`) without `...|cut -d "\n" -f`

```
0000000   1   9   2  \n   2   5   0  \n
0000010
```

Pseudocode

```
# http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/290407/16920
sed -n -f - /usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/us <<END_SED | cut -d "\n" -f1 
/xkb_symbols "dvorak" {/,/^};/{
        /xkb_symbols "dvorak" {/=
        /^};/=
}
END_SED
```

but blank output.

System: Ubuntu 16.04 64 bit
Hardware: Macbook Air 2013-mid
Sed: 4.2.2
Cut, od: Coreutils 8.25

Comment: what's wrong with @Kusalananda  's answer ?

Comment: I updated my answer to that question in such a way that the output is read into an array variable. The two values are then easily accessed through array index 0 and 1.

Comment: If you want the first *line* of output use `... | head -n 1`

Comment: @steeldriver Yes, it works, but I want the second line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `cut` utility "cuts" one or several *columns* out of its input. Like many other Unix utilities, `cut` is a stream-based line-by-line reader that applies its processing to each line of input and then contiues with the next line.

You can not use `\n` as the delimiter for `cut` since that is what it expects separate the lines.

A roundabout way of *creating* two columns for `cut` to work with would be to use `paste`.  The `paste` utility also reads it input line-by-line, but it buffers and outputs it into tab-delimited columns according to the specification that you give it.

In this case:

```
$ mycommand | paste - -
192     250
```

Then with `cut` added:

```
$ mycommand | paste - - | cut -f1
192
```

Comment: Actually, I like a lot more your method of storing just the array and accessing it by `pos[0],..., pos[1]` here http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/290407/16920 at the end.